# struggling with creating beans in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a registration security .

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


private UserService userService;
private EmailService emailService;

@Autowired
public UserController(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
        UserService userService, EmailService emailService) {
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.emailService = emailService;
}

// Return registration form template
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showRegistrationPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user){
    modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("register");
    return modelAndView;
}

// Process form input data
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processRegistrationForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // Lookup user in database by e-mail
    User userExists = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

    System.out.println(userExists);

    if (userExists != null) {
        modelAndView.addObject("alreadyRegisteredMessage", "Oops!  There is already a user registered with the email provided.");
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        bindingResult.reject("email");
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { 
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");       
    } else { // new user so we create user and send confirmation e-mail

        // Disable user until they click on confirmation link in email
        user.setEnabled(false);

        // Generate random 36-character string token for confirmation link
        user.setConfirmationTekn(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        userService.saveUser(user);

        String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();

        SimpleMailMessage registrationEmail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        registrationEmail.setTo(user.getEmail());
        registrationEmail.setSubject("Registration Confirmation");
        registrationEmail.setText("To confirm your e-mail address, please click the link below:\n"
                + appUrl + "/confirm?token=" + user.getConfirmationTekn());
        registrationEmail.setFrom("noreply@domain.com");

        emailService.sendEmail(registrationEmail);

        modelAndView.addObject("confirmationMessage", "A confirmation e-mail has been sent to " + user.getEmail());
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}

// Process confirmation link
@RequestMapping(value="/confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, 
@RequestParam("token") String token) {

    User user = userService.findByConfirmationToken(token);

    if (user == null) { // No token found in DB
        modelAndView.addObject("invalidToken", "Oops!  This is an invalid confirmation link.");
    } else { // Token found
        modelAndView.addObject("confirmationToken", user.getConfirmationTekn());
    }

    modelAndView.setViewName("confirm");
    return modelAndView;        
}

// Process confirmation link
@RequestMapping(value="/confirm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView confirmRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, RedirectAttributes redir) {

    modelAndView.setViewName("confirm");

    Zxcvbn passwordCheck = new Zxcvbn();

    Strength strength = passwordCheck.measure(requestParams.get("password"));

    if (strength.getScore() < 3) {
        //modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Your password is too weak.  Choose a stronger one.");
        bindingResult.reject("password");

        redir.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Your password is too weak.  Choose a stronger one.");

        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:confirm?token=" + requestParams.get("token"));
        System.out.println(requestParams.get("token"));
        return modelAndView;
    }

    // Find the user associated with the reset token
    User user = userService.findByConfirmationToken(requestParams.get("token"));

    // Set new password
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(requestParams.get("password")));

    // Set user to enabled
    user.setEnabled(true);

    // Save user
    userService.saveUser(user);

    modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Your password has been set!");
    return modelAndView;        
}

}
```

and my **MyWebMvc**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    return encoder;
}
}
```

and **UserService**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

public UserService() {

}

public User findByEmail(String email) {

    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);

}

public void saveUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

public User findByConfirmationToken(String token) {

    return userRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(token);
}

}
```

and the stacktrace is like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Point1\Point1\target\classes\com\point\application\Point1\controller\UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Point1\Point1\target\classes\com\point\application\Point1\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.point.application.Point1.Point1Application.main(Point1Application.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Point1\Point1\target\classes\com\point\application\Point1\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks that there is a property tokenConfirmation missing from User class:

"Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! ***No property tokenConfirmation found for type User***! "

Or maybe not missing but rather misspelled (tokenConfirmation or confirmationToken):

```
public User findByConfirmationToken(String token) {
    return userRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Java based configuration so Your MyWebMvc configuration class needs to have bean definition for UserService bean as well.

```
@Bean
 public UserService userService(){
      return new UserService();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jakub Godoniuk .. i did changing the property names like bellow

@Service("userService")
public class UserService {

```
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

public UserService() {

}

public User findByEmail(String email) {

    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);

}

public void saveUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

public User findByConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken) {

    return userRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(confirmationToken);
}
```

}

and below is resipository

```
@Repository("userRepository")
```

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository{

```
User findByEmail(String email);

User findByTokenConfirmation(String confirmationToken);
```

}

and my Entity

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name = "email")
@Email
@NotNull(message = "please enter a valid email")
private String email;

private String password;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public User(long id, @Email @NotNull(message = "please enter a valid email") String email,
        @NotNull(message = "please enter your first name") String firstname,
        @NotNull(message = "please enter you last_name") String lastname, boolean enabled, String password,
        String confirmationToken) {

    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.confirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    this.password = password;
}

public User() {

}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public String getConfirmationToken() {
    return confirmationToken;
}

public void setConfirmationTekn(String confirmationTekn) {
    this.confirmationToken = confirmationTekn;
}

@Column(name = "first_name")
@NotNull(message = "please enter your first name")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "last_name")
@NotNull(message = "please enter you last_name")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;

private String confirmationToken;
```

}

and i still get this exception:

Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Point1\Point1\target\classes\com\point\application\Point1\controller\UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Point1\Point1\target\classes\com\point\application\Point1\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.point.application.Point1.modal.User com.point.application.Point1.repository.UserRepository.findByTokenConfirmation(java.lang.String)! No property tokenConfirmation found for type User!